# AS3 Custom string formula parser

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air

My goal is to create some kind of Parser to parse string formulas, similar to Excel formulas.
Formula string example (barcode example) -

```
"CONCAT('98', ZEROFILL([productNumber],5,'0'), ZEROFILL(EQUATION([weightKG]*1000),5,'0'))"
```

where
 
`'98'` - String
`[productNumber]` and `[weightKG]` - are variables that can be changed
 
`CONCAT`, `ZEROFILL` and `EQUATION` are methods which exist in class

For this formula with variables `[productNumber] = '1'` and `[weightKG] = 0.1` result must be

```
'980000100100'
```

The question is how to split/parse whole string to parts and detect methods, variables and string values?
Another idea occurred, while i was typing - is to store whole formula in XML format.
Thank You.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [String.split()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/String.html#split%28%29) to get an array of substrings.

However, using your example, calling split(",") would give you the following array:

```
[0]=CONCAT('98'
[1]= ZEROFILL([productNumber]
[2]=5
[3]='0')
[4]= ZEROFILL(EQUATION([weightKG]*1000)
[5]=5
[6]='0'))
```

That doesn't seem like it will be very helpful for your project.  Instead, you might think about creating a parse() function with some logic to find useful substrings:

```
function parse(input:String):Array {
  var firstParen:int = input.indexOf("(");
  var lastParen:int = input.lastIndexOf(")");
  var formulaName:String = input.substring(0, firstParen);
  var arguments:String = input.substring(firstParen, lastParen);
  var argumentList:Array = parseArgs(arguments);
  var result:Array = new Array();

  result.push(formulaName);
  //Recursively call parse() on the argumentList 
  foreach (var elem:* in argumentList) {
    result.push(elem); //Could be string or array.
  }
}

function parseArgs(input:String):Array {
  // Look for commas that aren't enclosed inside parenthesis and 
  // construct an array of substrings based on that.  
  //A regex may be helpful here, but the implementation is left 
  //as an exercise for the reader.
}
```